# ¿Cómo inserto usando spring-data-jpa native query?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Estoy realizando un INSERT masivo con spring-data-jpa, la forma como lo estoy realizando es por conveniencia ya que se desea insertar 1 millon de registros desde XLS como batch, entonces al  realizarlo como objeto de spring-data-jpa con el save, siempre esta consultando para obtener el ID secuencial de la clave primaria.

La forma como realizo el insert es el siguiente:

**Resositorio:**

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO reparto.repositorio :templateTableRepositorio VALUES :substring", nativeQuery = true)
void saveAllOrdenesDeTrabajoInBulk(String templateTableRepositorio, String substring);
```

Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
2020-11-04 23:48:16.900 DEBUG 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    INSERT 
    INTO
        reparto.repositorio
        ? 
    VALUES
        ?
2020-11-04 23:48:16.901 DEBUG 17768 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : cnx-pool-easycloud - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@30a570a9: (connection was evicted)
2020-11-04 23:48:16.902 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://cadenadeconexion
2020-11-04 23:48:16.903 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         : PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.16
2020-11-04 23:48:16.903 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         :   setDefaultFetchSize = 0
2020-11-04 23:48:16.903 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         :   setPrepareThreshold = 5
2020-11-04 23:48:16.903 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to cadenadeconexion:5432
2020-11-04 23:48:17.064 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Receive Buffer Size is 65.536
2020-11-04 23:48:17.064 DEBUG 17768 --- [onnection adder] o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl        : Send Buffer Size is 65.536
2020-11-04 23:48:17.098 TRACE 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [(suministro, cliente, direccion_Suministro, nombre_Sector, direccion_Referencial_Suministro, sector_Id, ruta_Lectura_Id, orden_Lectura, ruta_Reparto_Id, orden_Reparto, postal, postal_Comentario_Entrega, ciclo_Id, periodo_Proceso_Id, tiene_Fise, es_Colectivo, es_Postal, tiene_Reclamo, serie_Medidor, latitud, longitud, flujo_Proceso_Id, flujo_Proceso_Fecha, unidad_Negocio_Id, orden_Trabajo_Id, proveedor_Id, empresa_Id, created_date, last_modified_date)]
2020-11-04 23:48:17.098 TRACE 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [(146741,'MARIA ISABEL HUAYNATE LLAMOCTANTA','JR MATEO DEL TORO Y ZAMBRANO - 1297 PISO 1 INT 2 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,1,351,1,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0039461 2018',-8.08169183,-79.0544837,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.874',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.875','2020-11-04 23:48:16.875'),(160099,'MARIA VIRGINIA ALAYO MAURICIO','JR GIRARDOT - 1359 PISO 1 INT B //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,2,351,2,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0043540 2018',-8.08142615,-79.04870226,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.875',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.875','2020-11-04 23:48:16.875'),(160124,'OLGA ROMERO BASTERES','JR GIRARDOT - 1359 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,3,351,3,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0043542 2018',-8.08142615,-79.04870226,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.875',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.875','2020-11-04 23:48:16.875'),(167907,'HENRY LUIS BLANCO CORNELIO','AV CAHUIDE - 126 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,4,351,4,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0047100 2018',-8.08132019,-79.05513271,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.876',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.876','2020-11-04 23:48:16.876'),(144016,'ADALILA SANTOS RODRIGUEZ RUIZ','JR PEDRO MURILLO - 1267 PISO 3 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,5,351,5,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0077094 2019',-8.08199297,-79.04593708,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.876',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.876','2020-11-04 23:48:16.876'),(103126,'PABLO JOSE TAPIA LAYZA','JR MATEO DEL TORO Y ZAMBRANO - 1150 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,6,351,6,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0029851 2018',-8.08143517,-79.05519658,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.876',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.877','2020-11-04 23:48:16.877'),(110506,'AGUSTINA BALCAZAR MENDOZA','AV CAHUIDE - 126 PISO 2 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,7,351,7,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0039270 2018',-8.08132019,-79.05513271,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.877',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.877','2020-11-04 23:48:16.877'),(110496,'AGUSTINA BALCAZAR MENDOZA','AV CAHUIDE - 126 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,8,351,8,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0039269 2018',-8.08132019,-79.05513271,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.877',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.877','2020-11-04 23:48:16.877'),(106192,'AUREA DEL PILAR JAVE ESPINOZA','AV CAHUIDE - 144 PISO 1 INT B //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,9,351,9,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034152 2018',-8.08114037,-79.05518882,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878','2020-11-04 23:48:16.878'),(102208,'ANITA MARLENE APOLITANO ESPINOZA','AV CAHUIDE - 144 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,10,351,10,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034123 2018',-8.08114037,-79.05518882,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878','2020-11-04 23:48:16.878'),(101959,'JORGE AUGUSTO URBINA VASQUEZ','AV CAHUIDE - 154 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,11,351,11,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0043227 2018',-8.08099718,-79.05526634,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878','2020-11-04 23:48:16.878'),(146045,'TEOFILO PAUL ROMERO JIMENEZ','AV CAHUIDE - 168 A PISO 3 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,12,351,12,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0038948 2018',-8.08088437,-79.05530851,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.878','2020-11-04 23:48:16.878'),(144621,'MARIBEL ROSA RONCAL JIMENEZ','AV CAHUIDE - 168 A PISO 2 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,13,351,13,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0038923 2018',-8.08088437,-79.05530851,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879','2020-11-04 23:48:16.879'),(106527,'MARCIAL OSTIANO ESPINOZA CENAS','AV CAHUIDE - 176 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,14,351,14,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0026751 2018',-8.08082165,-79.05533258,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879','2020-11-04 23:48:16.879'),(326231,'DOMINGO CUEVA ROSADO','AV CAHUIDE - 186 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,15,351,15,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0082090 2019',-8.08077416,-79.05534487,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.879','2020-11-04 23:48:16.879'),(331092,'DOMINGO CUEVA ROSADO','AV CAHUIDE - 186 PISO 1 INT C //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,16,351,16,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0082089 2019',-8.08077416,-79.05534487,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88','2020-11-04 23:48:16.88'),(326209,'DOMINGO CUEVA ROSADO','AV CAHUIDE - 186 PISO 1 INT B //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,17,351,17,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0082088 2019',-8.08077416,-79.05534487,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88','2020-11-04 23:48:16.88'),(205703,'ANTONIA CARMELA PECHE CHAUCA','AV CAHUIDE - 198 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,18,351,18,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0058425 2019',-8.08071301,-79.05541123,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.88','2020-11-04 23:48:16.88'),(107503,'MILTON RONAL ROBLES VALVERDE','AV CAHUIDE - 198 A PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,19,351,19,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0055547 2019',-8.08068952,-79.05541958,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881','2020-11-04 23:48:16.881'),(101947,'PAUL ROMI QUISPE DIAZ','JR MAIPU - 1401 PISO 2 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,20,351,20,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034142 2018',-8.08068364,-79.05531973,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881','2020-11-04 23:48:16.881'),(101952,'AGUSTIN PIO RODRIGUEZ GONZALES','CL LAURELES - 199 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,21,351,21,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0021847 2018',-8.08058694,-79.05515736,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881','2020-11-04 23:48:16.881'),(113040,'RAMON MALQUI RUBIO','JR ESMERALDA - 199 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,22,351,22,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0047115 2018',-8.08031792,-79.05455287,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.881','2020-11-04 23:48:16.881'),(112099,'MANUEL ISMAEL MALQUI FLORES','JR ESMERALDA - 198 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,23,351,23,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034996 2018',-8.08020614,-79.05424082,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882','2020-11-04 23:48:16.882'),(104188,'JUDITH CRISTINA MALQUI TOCAS','JR MAYPU - 1235 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,24,351,24,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0026616 2018',-8.08017261,-79.05416741,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882','2020-11-04 23:48:16.882'),(102377,'FRANCISCO JAVIER MALQUI AGUILAR','JR MAYPU - 1229 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,25,351,25,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034539 2018',-8.080141,-79.05409844,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882','2020-11-04 23:48:16.882'),(104171,'FLOR MARIA MALQUI AGUILAR','JR MAYPU - 1225 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,26,351,26,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034146 2018',-8.08010656,-79.05402295,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.882','2020-11-04 23:48:16.882'),(102363,'EDUARDO ELIBAN GUEVARA HILARIO','JR LIMA - 291 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,27,351,27,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034538 2018',-8.08012125,-79.05388082,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883','2020-11-04 23:48:16.883'),(110045,'FREDESVINDA MARQUINA ALFARO','JR LIMA - 281 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,28,351,28,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0029856 2018',-8.08021473,-79.05384373,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883','2020-11-04 23:48:16.883'),(106315,'LEONCIO CASTAÑEDA GAMBOA','JR LIMA - 267 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,29,351,29,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0034141 2018',-8.08044846,-79.05373493,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883','2020-11-04 23:48:16.883'),(105805,'JULIO CESAR BRICEÑO BOÑON','JR LIMA - 201 PISO 1 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,30,351,30,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0026760 2018',-8.08081156,-79.05349535,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883',1,18,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:48:16.883','2020-11-04 23:48:16.883')]
2020-11-04 23:48:17.268 DEBUG 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not execute statement [n/a]

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 33
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:107) [hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1510) [hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:295) [hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1612) [hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:238) [spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) [spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) [spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) [spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) [spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) [spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) [spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) [spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.saveAllOrdenesDeTrabajoInBulk(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.saveAllOrdenesDeTrabajoInBulk(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at pe.easy.cloud.repartoservice.services.impls.ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoImpl.guardarDataOrdenDeTrabajoInBulk(ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoImpl.java:176) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.easy.cloud.repartoservice.services.impls.ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e41fb599.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at pe.easy.cloud.repartoservice.services.impls.ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b9c8f13.guardarDataOrdenDeTrabajoInBulk(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.easy.cloud.repartoservice.controllers.ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoController.importarOrdenDeTrabajo(ImportarOrdenesDeTrabajoController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]

2020-11-04 23:48:17.269  WARN 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2020-11-04 23:48:17.269 ERROR 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 33
2020-11-04 23:48:17.275 DEBUG 17768 --- [nio-9091-exec-6] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
```

Pero si copio el insert que se genera en el log y lo pego a  mi base de datos lo realiza de  manera correcta.

Este es el insert que genera mi log.

```
 INSERT 
    INTO
        reparto.repositorio
        (suministro, cliente, direccion_Suministro, nombre_Sector, direccion_Referencial_Suministro, sector_Id, ruta_Lectura_Id, orden_Lectura, ruta_Reparto_Id, orden_Reparto, postal, postal_Comentario_Entrega, ciclo_Id, periodo_Proceso_Id, tiene_Fise, es_Colectivo, es_Postal, tiene_Reclamo, serie_Medidor, latitud, longitud, flujo_Proceso_Id, flujo_Proceso_Fecha, unidad_Negocio_Id, orden_Trabajo_Id, proveedor_Id, empresa_Id, created_date, last_modified_date) 
    VALUES
(146741,'MARIA ISABEL HUAYNATE LLAMOCTANTA','JR MATEO DEL TORO Y ZAMBRANO - 1297 PISO 1 INT 2 //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,1,351,1,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0039461 2018',-8.08169183,-79.0544837,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.63',1,16,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.63','2020-11-04 23:16:28.63'),(160099,'MARIA VIRGINIA ALAYO MAURICIO','JR GIRARDOT - 1359 PISO 1 INT B //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,2,351,2,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0043540 2018',-8.08142615,-79.04870226,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.631',1,16,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.631','2020-11-04 23:16:28.631'),(160124,'OLGA ROMERO BASTERES','JR GIRARDOT - 1359 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,3,351,3,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0043542 2018',-8.08142615,-79.04870226,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.635',1,16,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.635','2020-11-04 23:16:28.635'),(167907,'HENRY LUIS BLANCO CORNELIO','AV CAHUIDE - 126 PISO 1 INT A //LA ESPERANZA','LA ESPERANZA','null',4,351,4,351,4,'null','null',7,1,false,false,false,false,'0047100 2018',-8.08132019,-79.05513271,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.635',1,16,1,1,'2020-11-04 23:16:28.635','2020-11-04 23:16:28.635')
```

Por favor el apoyo si a alguien le ha pasado y como lo ha solucionado. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @JoelVasquezVillalobos  creería que el error que tienes es porque spring no dejara que insertes partes del query por variable los ha de interpretar como variables  String, lo que yo hago en este tipo de casos donde necesitas más control al generar una consulta SQL nativa es crear una clase donde realizas `@Autowire JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate` de esta forma puedes concatenar las variables a la consulta y ejecutarla utilizando `jdbcTemplate` recuerda que Spring-Data utiliza internamente `jdbcTemplate` por eso lo puedes inyectar.

Comment: Además un query nativo (nativeQuery = true) debe estar escrito en SQL puro segun la base de datos, y el tuyo esta en HQL por lo que estas mezclando conceptos, el sql que crees tiene que tener la llamada a la secuencia que genera los IDs dentro del insert a menos que sea autogenerado.

Comment: Hola @RobertoEMoran , entiendo la idea. Gracias.

Comment: espero que con esto puedas solventar tu problema, si tienes mas dudas actualiza a pregunta o crea una nueva.